# What is the private field name of actionbar context view ?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, robotium

A Hello ,,,
I'm using robotium framework for testing android apps and I used Robotium-actionbarsherlock extension to perform clicks on contextual actionbar menu item ...

Here's the function I'm using ,,,

```
public void clickOnActionModeOverflowMenuItem(String text) {
    Activity activity = solo.getCurrentActivity();
    Log.d("aaaa", activity.toString());
    if (!(activity instanceof SherlockFragmentActivity)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This method should be called only in SherlockFragmentActivity.");
    }

    ActionBarContextView actionBarContextView = null;

    try {
            ActionBarSherlock actionBarSherlock = (ActionBarSherlock) invokePrivateMethodWithoutParameters(
                SherlockFragmentActivity.class, "getSherlock", activity);
            Log.d("eeee", actionBarSherlock.toString());
            actionBarContextView = (ActionBarContextView) getPrivateField("mActionModeView", actionBarSherlock);
            Log.d("dddd", actionBarContextView.toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not find methods to invoke action mode overflow button.");
    }

    if (actionBarContextView == null) {
            Assert.fail("Contextual actionbar is not shown.");
    }

    actionBarContextView.showOverflowMenu();
    sleeper.sleep();
    clicker.clickOnText(text, false, 1, true, 0);
}
```

So, I'm asking about this line ..

```
actionBarContextView = (ActionBarContextView) getPrivateField("mActionModeView", actionBarSherlock);
```

How can I know the private field name ?
As the function fails and throws the assertion fail of null actionBarContextView ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source code for ActionBarSherlock, which should show you what you are looking for.